# What sort of RSpec test should I write for a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I am totally new to Rails and testing and I wrote this model:

```
class KeyPerformanceInd < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :organization_id, :target

  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many  :key_performance_intervals, :foreign_key => 'kpi_id'

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :target, presence: true
  validates :organization_id, presence: true

end
```

My question is for a model like that, what are some RSpec tests that I should write?
Somethings like this? Or there are moe things to do? I hear about **FactoryGirl**, Is that something I need for testing this model or that is for testing stuff in the controller?

```
Describe KeyPerformanceInd do
  it {should belong_to(:key_performance_interval)}
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to do more, and you can also use the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem to make your code really clean :

```
it { should belong_to(:organization) }
it { should have_many(:key_performance_intervals) }

it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:target) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:organization_id) }
```

And this is it.

You don't need `FactoryGirl` in this case, which is used to create valid and re-usable objects. But you could use factories in your model test. A simple example :

Your factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
  end
end
```

Your test :

```
it "should be valid with valid attributes" do  
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user.should be_valid
end
```

Check the [Factory Girl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) to have more informations.

Comment: thanks, so there are two gems, one is names shoulda and the other one is shoula-matchers , Do I need to include "both" ? or shoulda-mathers will automatically use shoulda  internally?

Comment: shoulda-matchers is a dependency of shoulda but you can simply include shoulda-matchers. Put in in the group test of your Gemfile.